# EF4 Object State is unchange for newly added rows even change a property

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have a issue with updating records within the same context.

Ex scenario is as follows.

I have a Data entry from and add one record from it. Insert is happens withing transaction scope.

I add record from the same form and try to change the values. it dosnt work. When I see the object state it is unchanged even property value is changed.

updates will work correctly after I restart the application and change the values. After that all changes affecting correctly.

This happens only the records inserted withing the context.

SaveChages() is called without any Parameter.

Any body has idea about this issue ?

DineshNS

Comment: is this a web or win app? post some of the code were you add ur first and second entities

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
ObjectContext.ApplyCurrentValues("EntitySetName", currentEntity);
```

Eg: `ObjectContext.ApplyCurrentValues("Orders", Order);`

Comment: Hi Thank you for the reply. If we do it explicitly it will work. My issue is do we need to set it explicitly ? Changing a property value isn't enough for this ?

Comment: Your suggestion works. Do we need to do this every time when we update record ?.

Comment: As mentioned in the below link,you need to do this Every time ur Entity is updated outside of ObjectContext: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487246.aspx.

Comment: by "outside Object Context", it could mean, you pass the entity to a different layer/app, get it back with updated values, you need to associate it to the Entity in the Object Context. "ApplyCurrenytValues" does this by associating the detached object that has property updates to apply to the original object by associating them with the Entity Key.